# How can I Access-Control-Allow-Origin on signalR C# angular5

Tags: c#, angular, cors, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using angular 5 and C# API , and I'm trying to implement SignalR for push notifications ; and I'm stuck on this error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

I'm using ng-signalr on angular5

[image]

I did something wrong and i don't know where

**startup.cs**

```
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace App5
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {

            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();


            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            //  Enable attribute based routing
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}/{code}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional , action = RouteParameter.Optional, code = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
            appBuilder.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**Ng2SignalRHub.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App5
{
    [Authorize]
    [HubName("Ng2SignalRHub")]
    public class Ng2SignalRHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {

            Trace.TraceInformation("Ng2SignalRHub - OnConnected");

            var user = GetAuthenticatedUser();

            Clients.All.OnUserConnected(user);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        private string GetAuthenticatedUser()
        {
            var username = Context.QueryString["user"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
                throw new System.Exception("Failed to authenticate user.");

            Trace.TraceInformation("GetAuthenticatedUser :" + username);

            return username;
        }
    }

}
```

Please can anyone has the solution for this issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link and see if it helps: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1400

Since SignalR is in preview with asp.net core 2.1 you have to make sure that all versions of the client packages match. You should also be configuring a CORS Policy

In ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:50000");
        }));
       services.AddSignalR();
```

In Configure:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt ; Sorry I'm newbie on .net technology in my question I'm using webform application not a ASP.net so are this instructions will work also ol the webform api ? If yes can you give me some extra details ! Thank you

Comment: @Dev from your original code post it appears that you are using .NET Core 2. If you are developing a web app then you would be using ASP.NET Core 2 by default. Based on the configurations and code examples this does not look at all like a traditional .NET Framework 4 Webforms app. How did you create your project?

Comment: Visual C# -> windows classic desktop -> Windows from app ; but I fixed the problem by adding **appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);** into my startup file